# Graph REST API [Mail] how to downlod an email .eml with attachments inside

Tags: java, email, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

the following code it's my call to retrieve an EML file, but I need to retrieve also the attachments inside it.
How can I do it ?

```
jsonAttach = (StringResponse) Unirest.get(
                        String.format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/messages/%s/$value", 
                                user_email,tempMailId))
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .header("Authorization", tokenType + " " + accessToken)
                        .asString();
```

Comment: Have you tried like this (GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value)?

Comment: Does it worked?

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thank you!!

Comment: Wonderful @Cardo. Glad to hear that the above helped. Please feel free to upvote or mark as answered, so it can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

I tried the following API call and it worked for me.

```
GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages{id}/attachments/{id}/$value)
```